# VLCPlugin2 rtsp freezes with low network-caching. Trying to detect crash

Tags: vb.net, vlc, rtsp

I am using VLCPlugin2 in VB.net to watch a live RTSP Stream. I need it to be live as possible so I have been messing with the network-caching commandline option. 250ms crashes very easy and 300ms will crash after a few minutes. While I could increase the cache to 500ms which is on the upper end what I could tolerate I figure over time I could also get a crash. I would like to find a way to detect this crash so that I can restart the stream with a higher cache.. Starting at 300-350ms and if I keep crashing I keep bumping it each time I replay.  when I crash AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.isPlaying is still true.. im hoping maybe i can detect if VLCPlugin2 is throwing an exception and handle it..

```
Dim ip1 As String = "192.168.5.231"
Dim rtsp1a As String = "rtsp://192.168.5.231:554/user=admin&password=admin&channel=1&stream=0.sdp"
Dim options As String = ":no-video-title-show :network-caching=350 "
AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.add(rtsp1a, , options)
AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.playItem(0)
```

Comment: *How* are you "using VLCPlugin2 in VB.net"?  Could you post some code?

Comment: I try to reproduce this with: rtsp://quicktime.uvm.edu:1554/waw/wdi05hs2b.mov
And all works fine.
So, I think it's problem with your stream. Try my stream uri.